# Filemaker Uploading Image to Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, filemaker

I am using wordpress filemaker Sync plugin to upload database from filemaker to wordpress post. all the images are container but when I run the script, it keeps on showing error. there is no such file or directory. I have no ideas what is going on. I have double checked the images are stored in the filemaker correctly and I have follow the plugin instruction correctly but it keeps on showing no such file or directory.

Comment: WordPress FileMaker Sync has free email support, including trial version. They would be the people to talk to.

Comment: I know; however, I have been trying to contact them for a while and I haven't heard anything from them. This is why I ask the question. I think it maybe something to do with my field container but I am totally new to filemaker so I dont have any idea.

Comment: When you insert an image into a container field you can specify to store only reference to the file (this is a checkbox on the file select dialogue). Try to insert the image with this option on and then upload to WP

Comment: Hi Nicolai, I did try the only reference and the directory were my computer directory. I think there is something wrong with my directory. The Server is WEB_Product, Table is WEB_Product. The error shows like this " ERROR fmnet:/#host/ Files/WEB_Product/WEB_Product/Product_spec/photo_product_tc02104wxx01.png(No such file pr directory) Is it something wrong with my directory? Is it possible to modify? Thank you.

Comment: fmnet is the FileMaker protocol to open/connect to FileMaker files. This is a URL and not the filepath

Comment: I suspect it is the firewall setup, try to temporarily disable the firewall on that server

Comment: Hi Nicolai, I did disable my wp website firewall and it didnt work. I am able to upload all the text data but when it comes to image, it keeps on showing the error. I can upload the text data to wp website but not image. Does it mean that it is probably not about firewall and it's something else ?

Comment: My Container field option set as External (Open). If I dont set anything, it will show that I have to set it as External.

Comment: I was talking about the firewall on your FileMaker server, not WP server

Comment: Yes I did check for FileMaker server and it doesnt have one.

Comment: As I said before, WordPress FileMaker support should be able to help. Try to call them on +1 312 544 0244

Answer (score 1):

I have made an entire powerpoint on the pros and cons of FileMaker storage options. By reference is usually not a good option, which I will explain. Are you trying to upload from a hosted location to WordPress? "By reference" only really works as expected on the client side, and not on the server side.

FileMaker Server only supports file references from two locations on the server side, which are the `<documents>` and `<temporary>` directories. For example, the documents path on Server running windows is `/C:/Program Files/FileMaker/FileMaker Server/Data/Documents/`. The next caveat is that only text-based documents are available by reference at those locations, so even if you set it up correctly for images, it will say that the image was not found or that the path is invalid.

I Assume you do not want to store the data embedded in the solution file, due to bloat. You may want to try that out just for testing purposes before moving on. The solution which has worked for me is using FileMaker's "canned" External storage option, which I have found to be quite flexible. It will store container data relative to the "hosted" location of the solution, which is just wherever the solution resides on the server. You specify a base directory, and then subdirectories relative to that base directory. Using this option, FileMaker can now access its images in a familiar format and I suspect that will solve your "no such path or directory" error working with your plugin.